# MYSQLDUMP to CSV file with option --single-transaction

Tags: mysql

I have a very big table in my database, i want to backup and replicate to another slave server.

The best one i think is to export that table's data to csv file and import those to the slave server via the command sqlimport ( it runs faster than mysql )

So my question is how can i export the table's data to csv file when the database is running ? 
Is it possible to activate the option --single-transaction in using mysqldump ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I dump a table and export to csv:

```
select * from product where datecreated between '2013-08-01' and '2013-11-11' order by datecreated desc     INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/xmas2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
```

Then navigate to your tmp directory and open the csv.

Volterony

Answer (score 0):

Create the table on your slave host.

From your shell on your slave server:

#nohup  mysqldump -h"ip or host of your master server" -uuser -p "DB_NAME" "TABLE_NAME" | mysql –user=user –password=password "name_of_your_database" &

If you are traying with Master and Slave replication.

1.- Config the production server as a master

A) Edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf on [mysqld] section:

server-id=1

binlog-format = mixed

log-bin=mysql-bin

datadir=/var/lib/mysql

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

sync_binlog=1

B) Restart the server

C) CREATE USER replicant@slavehost/ip:port;

GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO replicant@slavehost/ip:port IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

2.-Make backup of Mysql database in to the backupserver.create the backup file with the binlog 
position.

# nohup mysqldump -uroot -p --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 -A > dump_DBNAME .sql

3.- Save the MASTER_LOG_FILE and MASTER_LOG_POS

#head dump_DBNAME .sql | grep "MASTER_LOG_FILE" > MASTER_LOG_FILE_DBNAME .sql

#head dump_DBNAME .sql | grep "MASTER_LOG_POS" > MASTER_LOG_POS_DBNAME .sql

4.-Config the slave server

Edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

server-id = 10

binlog-format = mixed

log_bin = mysql-bin

relay-log = mysql-relay-bin

log-slave-updates = 1

read-only = 1

5.- Restore the backup into the slave server:

Otion 1: Commpress the de dump file gzip dump_DBNAME .sql and transfer with FTP or send as an email.

Then restor the backup from the slave server

#gunzip dump_DBNAME .sql.gz

# mysqldump -hORIGINALHOST -uUSERNAME -p < dump_DBNAME .sql

Option 2: make the backup directly from the master server to the slave server

# nohup mysql –mysqldump -hslavehost -uUSERNAME -p dump_DBNAME .sql < dump_DBNAME .sql &

6.-Config the slave server

Edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

server-id = 10

binlog-format = mixed

log_bin = mysql-bin

relay-log = mysql-relay-bin

log-slave-updates = 1

read-only = 1

Start the Slave Server

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master-server-ip',MASTER_USER='replicant',MASTER_PASSWORD='slave-server-password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='value log file', MASTER_LOG_POS='value log pos';

10.- Start and Review the state of the slave

START SLAVE;

SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G

At this point we have a copy of the Original server in the Slave Server